# ServiceStack IOC not injecting property in Attribute (object is null)

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I'm trying to log/persist all my requests/responses, and thought that I give it a try with a global attribute, but when I go to actually using the repo, it's null? Is this possible?

Are there other ways to achieve what I'm looking to do?

Thank you,
Stephen

**Attribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class LogRequestAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute 
{
    public IRepository Repo { get; set; }

    public LogRequestAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo)
        : base(applyTo)
    {
        this.Priority = -200;
    }

    public LogRequestAttribute()
        : this(ApplyTo.All) {}

    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        try
        {
            // Convert the req obj into something that can be persisted...

            Repo.LogRequest("Logging the rquest");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**AppHost Config**

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
    ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

    //Show StackTrace in Web Service Exceptions
    SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { DebugMode = true });


    //Register any dependencies you want injected into your services
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

/*            // Redis
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager());
    container.Register<IRepository>(c => new Repository(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()));*/


    container.Register<IRepository>(new Repository());
    container.Register<IBusinessService>(new BusinessService());

    //Configure Custom User Defined REST Paths for your services
    /*ConfigureServiceRoutes();*/

    //Add a request filter to check if the user has a session initialized
    /*this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
    {
        var sessionId = httpReq.GetCookieValue("user-session");
        if (sessionId == null)
        {
            httpResp.ReturnAuthRequired();
        }
    });*/


    RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) => new LogRequestAttribute().Execute(httpReq, httpResp, requestDto));
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void LogRequest(string request);
    void LogResponse(string request);
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger("API.Repository");

    public Repository()
    {

    }

    public void LogRequest(string request)
    {
        Log.Debug(request);
    }

    public void LogResponse(string request)
    {
        Log.Debug(request);
    }
}
```

**Updated**

```
//Add a 'global' request filter
this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
{
    /* Code here */
});


//Add a 'global' response filter
this.ResponseFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, responseDto) =>
{
    /* Code here */
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to log requests in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) you should look to see if [Request Logger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) plugin is useful. The [RequestLogsFeature Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Admin/RequestLogsFeature.cs) allows you to use your own custom [IRequestLogger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IRequestLogger.cs) instead of the [InMemoryRollingRequestLogger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Providers/InMemoryRollingRequestLogger.cs) that's used by default.

#### Filter Attributes

Although you've defined a Request Filter attribute correctly you're not applying it correctly, which should be used just like any other C# Attribute (i.e. decorated). [Filter Attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) can **only** be decorated on either the **Service Type**, its **Request DTO** or a Service **Action** where it is only run to the scope they are applied to.

#### Global Request Filters

There is **no Global** Request Filter **Attribute**, the [Global Request filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) only let you specify a delegate to get executed, which is all that's happening here:

```
RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) => 
  new LogRequestAttribute().Execute(httpReq, httpResp, requestDto));
```

A new instance of the **LogRequestAttribute** type is constructed inline (and as seen above, is not resolved from the IOC) so it is not auto-wired. The fact that the method you're calling is an instance of a FilterAttribute is irrelevant since all the C# delegate is calling is a method on an empty LogRequestAttribute instance.

If registering a global filter inside `Configure()` you can access the `container` directly, e.g:

```
RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) => 
  container.Resolve<IRepository>().LogRequest("Logging the request"));
```

Anywhere else, you can access ServiceStack's IOC with the singleton: `AppHostBase.Resolve<T>()`.

Comment: OK, so hypothetically if I wanted to log response/request I _could_ do it with the Global Request/Response filter delegates. Every post related to the filters has always mentioned the IRequestLogger.. guess it's time to implement that interface. Thanks for answering on a weekend  Demis.